# Axios 302 responses

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to get the response headers of a website that is "temporarily moved" whenever I do so it just redirects me. I've done it with fiddler to try and get a clear image in my head and I just can't wrap my head around how I would do it with Axios. Basically I'm trying to get the headers of the site before the redirect happens. If that isn't possible what else should I use to do so automatically?

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const readline = require('readline');
const title = require('node-bash-title')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
console.clear()
var loopline = function () {
rl.question('Input: ', (answer) => {    
    axios.get(`https://example302site.com/${answer}`, {
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.headers)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(`AssetId: ${error.response.body}`)
        loopline()
    })
})
}
loopline()
```

(Sorry for messy code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios has a [request config option](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) `maxRedirects` which allows you to control the number of redirects. Setting it to `0` should prevent getting redirected and allows you to read the response-headers:

```
axios.get(`https://assetgame.roblox.com/asset/?versionid=5667870400`, {
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Roblox/WinInet' },
        maxRedirects: 0
      })
```

Comment: Using maxRedirects does not work. Using Edge, I still end up with the already forwarded request, getting a 200 from subsequent request. The browser is hiding the forward from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[non-Nodejs solution] maxRedirects is only supported in Nodejs [(link)](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/674). This means that if you use it in your browser (js code), redirects will still happen.

Alternative solution:
use fetch() with `redirect` options is `manual`
[(learn more here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Example:

```js
fetch(requestUrl, {
  redirect: "manual",
})
.then((response) => {
  // do something...
  console.log(response);
  // please note the headers will not be printable with console.log and the is no way to obtain the `Location` header but the other is ok
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```